# MySQL query optimization using Indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table with Postal codes with over 150k records.

When I run this query

```
select count(*) as total_count from pincodes where pincode = '834009';
```

I get following stats in my slow query log.

```
SET timestamp=1390221731;
select count(*) as total_count from pincodes where pincode = '834009';
# Query_time: 12.261122  Lock_time: 0.000067 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 154727
```

Can I optimize it using indexes? What should my index look like? Or any other way to optimize this query?

**Edit**: There are records with same value for `pincode` column. Just wanted to let you know in case this makes any difference.

Thanks.

Comment: yes... index on (pincode)

Comment: I will add and let you know. Thanks

Comment: [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really)

Comment: Thanks Bill, I will go through that as well.